# Is it possible to apply dictionaries for Citrus static response adapter response template?

Tags: citrus-framework

I'm using Citrus static response adapter to mock services, and I need to change values in its payload for every test case. Ideally I think about usage of dictionaries for each test case. There is sample of my current scenario:

```
@Autowired
@Qualifier("checkRegistrationEndpointAdapter")
public StaticResponseEndpointAdapter checkRegistrationEndpointAdapter;

protected void setAdapterResponse(StaticResponseEndpointAdapter adapter, String filenamepath){
    URL url = this.getClass().getResource(filenamepath);
    String payload = null;
    try {
        payload = Resources.toString(url, Charsets.UTF_8);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    adapter.setMessagePayload(payload);
}
@CitrusTest
public void TestCase02() throws IOException {

    http()
            .client(CLIENT)
            .post()
            .payload(new ClassPathResource("templates/thisStartRequestMsg.xml", getClass()))
            .dictionary("TC02");

    http()
            .client(CLIENT)
            .response()
            .messageType("xml")
            .payload(new ClassPathResource("templates/thisStartResponseMsg.xml", getClass()));

    action(new AbstractTestAction() {
        @Override
        public void doExecute(TestContext testContext) {
            setAdapterResponse(checkRegistrationEndpointAdapter, "templates/check-registration-v1CheckRegistrationResponseMsg.xml");
        }
    });

    http()
            .client(CLIENT)
            .response()
            .messageType("xml")
            .payload(new ClassPathResource("templates/check-registration-v1CheckRegistrationRequestMsg.xml", getClass()))
            .dictionary("TC02");
}
```

How can I apply dictionary to the payload set in my *setAdapterResponse* method?
Note: this question relates to [Can I use Citrus variable in Citrus static response adapter payload?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40388363/can-i-use-citrus-variable-in-citrus-static-response-adapter-payload)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Static response adapter has currently no support for data dictionaries. I wonder why you put so much effort into static response adapters? Why not using the full Citrus http server power with receiving the request and providing a response inside the test case?

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I tried with static response adapters because I hadn't have answered https://github.com/christophd/citrus-samples/issues/10 that time.